# How can Javascript's regular expressions filter strings with multiple rules at the same time?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I need to process a piece of text into an array of words.

Delimiters between words are newlines, spaces, and various punctuation marks, and `&nbsp;`.

The code I wrote was able to handle other cases, but not the `&nbsp;` case.

> Notice:I need to handle all cases within the same regex and cannot replace `&nbsp;` with spaces.

---

This code doesn't go wrong, it just runs in **chrome** and the result is not the expected value.

> In the generated word array, `"break up test the  words"` is a value(wrong), I need it to be 5: `[break,up,test,the,words]`(right)

---

my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var text = document.getElementById('text').textContent
  // &nbsp; of below regex doesn't work
  var word_array = text.split(/[ \t\n\r.?,"';:!(){}<>\/]|&nbsp;/)
  console.log(text)
  console.log(word_array)
}
</script>
</head><body>
<div id="text">this   is text,break&nbsp;up&nbsp;test&nbsp;the&nbsp;&nbsp;words!ok</div>
</body></html>
```

---

Comment: Working fine on Firefox

Comment: This code doesn't go wrong, it just runs in **chrome** and the result is not the expected value

Comment: In the generated word array, `"break up test the  words"` is a value(wrong), I need it to be 5: `[break,up,test,the,words]`(right)

Comment: Maybe the flag "g" is missing at the end of the last regex `/`?

Comment: I just found out that using /\s/ does the same thing, or even better. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the regex sees &nbsp as those exact characters. You want to use '\xa0' instead.

Comment: yes,i changed the regex to `/[ \t\n\r.?,"';:!(){}<>\/]|\xa0|\x20/`, it worked, thanks

Comment: I just found out that using `/\s/` does the same thing, or even better. thanks